# Why are these links in .NET MVC / Ratchet application not working?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, ratchet-bootstrap

When I click on links they do not seem to work. When I right click them and open in a new tab they open correctly.

I can't figure out the reason for this behavior.

Here is the code for my **_layout.cshtml** file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    ...
    <!-- Roboto -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,500,700">

    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/ratchet")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/ratchet")

</head>
<body>

    <div class="content">
        @RenderBody()
    </div>
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
</body>
</html>
```

And here is an example of a link I'd put in **index.cshtml**

```
  <a href="@Url.Action("NewList", "Home", null)">Submit</a>
  <a href="/Home/NewList">Submit 2</a>
```

Both static and generated behave the same leading me to think this is a Ratchet issue.

**EDIT 1** 
Apparently even the toggle is not working (again no JS errors)

```
<div class="toggle active">
  <div class="toggle-handle"></div>
</div>
<div class="toggle">
  <div class="toggle-handle"></div>
</div>
```

It works in a plain HTML template so I must assume this is from a **.Render** issue?

http://goratchet.com/components/

**EDIT 2:** 
Many of the components don't seem to be working, I've found a way to bypass this issue by replacing the links with forms that have a submit button and hidden values to POST to the required Action. 
Terrible for the UI but at least the buttons are working.

Comment: Nothing sounds wrong in it, can you check it in a different browser, might b some plugin is messing up the things.

Comment: You might be able to work around it by adding target="_blank" to your link attributes. I don't really know how Ratchet works, but it sounds hilarious.

Comment: Same behavior on Chrome, FireFox, and latest IE

Comment: Even with different "target" values it still only opens when I click on new tab.

Comment: one thing which I suffered few days back that there was a div which was semi over lapping the hyperlink, so if I click on above center of text nothing was happening but if i click on below the center, link was working fine, I hope its not the case with you.

Comment: Are you receiving any javascript errors in your console when you click the links?

Comment: No, no errors,  could this be a problem with @Scripts.Render ?

Comment: Have you commented out Ratchet to see if the problem goes away?

Comment: Yes I have, and it does

Answer (score 0):

Do you have both regular and `.min` versions of ratchet so it can be loaded via your `/bundles/ratchet` bundle? Make sure you have both, or if you only have the debug versions that you are running in debug mode (or if you have only the `.min` versions that you are running not in debug mode)

Comment: I'm on debug and I have tried both `.min` and regular files

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes “HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found” error is encountered when calling the view. One of the possible cause for this error just a dot (.) in the href. In case this problem is caused from the same issue try as below (attention to dot):

```
<a href="@Url.Action("NewList", "Home")">Submit</a>
<a href="./Home/NewList">Submit 2</a>
```

**Update:**

When creating a link to a controller action in ASP.NET MVC, using the generic ActionLink method is preferable, because it allows for strongly typed links that are refactoring friendly:

```
@Html.ActionLink("NewList", "Home")
```

Hope this helps...

Comment: Same issue, Links appear to be correct when I hover (and when I right click and open in a new tab) but they don't seem to click when simply clicking on them. 
Buttons work tho. 
I double checked all the JS files and even CSS, very strange.

Comment: Have you tried with dot(.)? On the other hand try to use "@Url.Action" without "null" parameter as on my updated code?

Comment: Yes I have tested your updated code. They don't seem to be clickable. 

I have been working on this for a week, I think I'm going to just turn every link to a button and call it a day.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to move the links from body to head.

```
 @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")

 @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
```

Move them to head section once.